# Como Posicionar com CSS o Quick AdSense

Tags: css

Tenho um Site Recente e Adicionei o Quick AdSense, depois de ter sido aprovado, mas os Anúncios desconfiguram, ou melhor desconfiguravam as Páginas, então encontrei uma resposta a uma pergunta aqui no StackOverflow em inglês, que eu não sei muito e, infelizmente não guardei o Link dessa Respopsta, onde diziam para colocar o Código do Adsense dentro de uma DIV com uma ID e Aplicar Regras ao Style, o que eu fiz, alterando alguns pormenores como mostro a seguir:

```
#adsense {
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
width: 100%;
top: 150px;
}
```

Desde ontem que fiz estas alterações, que me parece que já está tudo OK, mas ainda assim, queria perguntar a alguém que saiba mais do que eu de CSS, se ainda falta algo para funcionar melhor e em todos os navegadores do Site: https://www.publicacoes-digitais-index.com/
Muito Obrigado, desde já!

Comment: Parece que ainda Falta algo para o Footer, algumas Páginas não mostram o último Anúncio no Footer, alguma Ajuda?

Answer (score 0):

Parece que era algum Problema de Compatibilidade com um Calendário em Javascrip que eu tinha no Sidebar, passei o dito cujo para um Pop-up mediante Onclick e, desde então que me parece estar tudo OK agora!
Talvez também fosse o armazenamento em cache do meu Navegador!
Então, para alguém que enfrente os mesmos problemas que tive, fica a dica:

```
HTML

<div id="adsense">
Código do Quick Adsense Aqui!
</div>

CSS

#adsense {
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
width: 100%;
top: 150px;
}

E Funcionou para mim!
```